React Native - Webview css issue rendering
i have the next issue rendering some site using webview:

But this is the result from any chrome product and is what i want:


A tried a lot of things:

Downgrading and upgrading webview
headers
activate/desactivate acceleation password
activa js, dom
deleting cache, etc

My screen code:
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const Main_Screen = () => {
  return (
    <WebView
  source={{ uri: '' }}
  injectedJavaScriptBeforeContentLoaded={`document.documentElement.style.height = "100%";`}
  javaScriptEnabled={true}
  domStorageEnabled={true}
  startInLoadingState={true}
/>
  );
};

export default Main_Screen;

Quetion

How i can get the same result for any product?

Even, webview is not loading properly accent-color for checkbox selection
This is the code of my site:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Modal B Sheet</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Urbanist:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles/bscore_style.css" />
     <script src="./src/js/bscore_script.js" type="module"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="gc-core-bottom-sheet">
      <!-- <div class="sheet-overlay"></div> -->
      <div class="gc-core-content-sheet">
        <div class="gc-core-sheet-content">
          <h2>Bottom Sheet Modal</h2>
          <p>Create a bottom sheet modal that functions similarly to Fact</p>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae ipsum
            quidem quam sed nisi autem, ratione repudiandae magnam. Itaque
            sapiente doloremque qui quam? Vitae fugiat, unde hic illum labore
            architecto.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./src/js/bscore_script.js" defer></script>
  </body>
</html>



* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Urbanist", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #e3f2fd;
}

.gc-core-bottom-sheet {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
}

.gc-core-bottom-sheet.show {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.gc-core-bottom-sheet .gc-core-content-sheet {
  background: #fff;
  height: 50vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  padding: 25px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.gc-core-bottom-sheet.show .gc-core-content-sheet {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.gc-core-bottom-sheet .gc-core-bottom-sheet-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0 40px;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.gc-core-bottom-sheet .gc-core-bottom-sheet-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

.gc-core-bottom-sheet .gc-core-bottom-sheet-content h2 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.gc-core-bottom-sheet .gc-core-bottom-sheet-content p {
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


const bottomSheet = document.querySelector(".gc-core-bottom-sheet");
const sheetContent = bottomSheet.querySelector(".gc-core-content-sheet");

let isDragging = false,
  startY,
  startHeight;

const showBottomSheet = () => {
  bottomSheet.classList.add("show");
  document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
  updateSheetHeight(140); /* altura inicial */
};

const updateSheetHeight = (height) => {
  sheetContent.style.height = `${height}px`;
  bottomSheet.classList.toggle(height === 100); /* para redondear bordes en full screen */
};

const hideBottomSheet = () => {
  // bottomSheet.classList.remove("show");
  document.body.style.overflowY = "auto";
};

const dragStart = (e) => {
  isDragging = true;
  startY = e.pageY || e.touches?.[0].pageY;
  startHeight = parseInt(sheetContent.style.height);
  bottomSheet.classList.add("dragging");
};

const dragging = (e) => {
  if (!isDragging) return;
  const delta = startY - (e.pageY || e.touches?.[0].pageY);
  const newHeight =
    startHeight + (delta / window.innerHeight) * 100; /* sensibilidad */
  updateSheetHeight(newHeight);
};

const dragStop = () => {
  isDragging = false;
  bottomSheet.classList.remove("dragging");
  const sheetHeight = parseInt(sheetContent.style.height);
  sheetHeight < 55
    ? hideBottomSheet()
    : sheetHeight > 15
    ? updateSheetHeight(100) /* al arrastrar hacia arriba */
    : updateSheetHeight(20); /* al arrastrar hacia abajo */
};

showBottomSheet();


